# Grails change web-app static directory

Tags: grails

I'm running an application through grails 2.2.4. As it stands, grails handles all requests from the base of the "web-app/" directory. Unfortunately, all the URI references in my web-application are of the type "app/images", "app/styles", "app/scripts", etc. This means that any call to "/images" is hitting "web-app/images", instead of the true "web-app/app/images". Is there a simple way to prefix on an additional "/app/" in front of all calls?

file structure:

```
  /web-app
    /app
      /images
      /styles
      /scripts
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Resources plugin (which I think you would be), then have a look at the [configuration](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html) section.

You would need the below settings in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.resources.work.dir = '/app/'

//if a prefix is required other than 'static'
grails.resources.uri.prefix = '/content/'
```

Comment: Does this mean all my refs need to be `href: {$resources: dir: file:}` style?

Comment: No, not necessary. The config is just to inform the app where to look for the static resources. Everything else stays the same.

Comment: This doesn't do the trick. I can change the prefix, but all that does is modify the raw value of '/static/', not change the directory served. I can hit my resources with `/app/images/cat.png`, which is actually redirected by grails to `/static/images/cat.png'.